# Triggering animation after another animation

Tags: amp-html

Currently I have an `amp-img`

```
<amp-img id="fade" src="https://picsum.photos/576/233" width="576" height="233" alt="AMP"></amp-img>
```

This image fades in and to the right with an animation.

```
{
    "selector": "#fade",
    "keyframes":
    {
        "opacity": [0, 1],
        "transform": ["translateX(-100px)", "translateX(0)"]
    }
},
```

Is it possible to trigger another animation in sequential order? Right now everything happens all at once.

I am aware I can use `delay`...however, because the `amp-img` is loading asynchronously, the delay time could ultimately vary. It depends when the image is loaded. It could load instantly or it could load in a few seconds. Is there a way with amp-animation to account for this?